# in swift how to wait until all skaction are finished

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction

i have some object SKSprite, when touch it i run SKAction (scale and color) when we touch all good sprite (bloc) i want to run another action "unselect all bloc"
for do this i run on each sksprite an action scale and color (to go to original color), but i see strange effect, actions are not queued
some bloc don't go back to original size, that's mean the scale not finished.
i can't understand why, i can run all action in same time, because the initial scale and color is made when touch sprite and the unselect all sprite is made after the last sprite is selected
not sure i have good explain ?

Code running on class GameBloc (aka SKSprite)

```
class GameBloc : SKSpriteNode
```

animation function in GameBloc class

```
func animateBloc()
{
    let withDuration:Double         = Constants.UI.C_0101100_GAMEPLAY_ANIMATION_DURATION
    let initialBlocScale:CGFloat    = self.xScale
    let initialFontScale:CGFloat    = self.label!.xScale
    let scaleBlocLessAction = SKAction.scale(to: (initialBlocScale * 0.85) , duration: (withDuration/2.0))
    let scaleBlocNormalAction = SKAction.scale(to: initialBlocScale , duration: (withDuration/2.0))
    let scaleLabelLessAction = SKAction.scale(to: (initialFontScale * 0.85) , duration: (withDuration/2.0))
    let scaleLabelNormalAction = SKAction.scale(to: initialFontScale , duration: (withDuration/2.0))
    var blocColor:Int = Constants.UI.C_0101100_COLOR_BLOC_SELECTED
    var labelColor:Int = Constants.UI.C_0101100_COLOR_BLOC_SELECTED_LABEL

    // coloration en fonction du select ou unselect, le reste est identique
    if(self.selected==false)
    {
        blocColor = Constants.UI.C_0101100_COLOR_MEDIUMGRAY
        labelColor = Constants.UI.C_0101100_COLOR_BLOC_LABEL
    }
    let colorBlocAction = SKAction.colorize(with: Constants.UI.colorsArray[self.appDelegate.theme][blocColor], colorBlendFactor: 1, duration: withDuration)
    let colorLabelAction = self.changeColorForLabelNode(toColor: Constants.UI.colorsArray[self.appDelegate.theme][labelColor],withDuration: withDuration)

    // animation de coloration
    self.run(SKAction.group([SKAction.sequence([scaleBlocLessAction, scaleBlocNormalAction]), colorBlocAction]))
    self.label?.run(SKAction.group([SKAction.sequence([scaleLabelLessAction, scaleLabelNormalAction]), colorLabelAction]))
}
```

and what i do to unselect all blocs
this is call in GameScene

```
func unSelectAllBlocs()
{
    // on va deselectionner tous les blocs actuellement selectionne
    for index:Int in stride(from: 0, to: blocSelectedArray.count, by: 1)
    {
        // on deselectionne les blocs
        print("** Unselect bloc at index=\(blocSelectedArray[index])")
        blocArray[blocSelectedArray[index]].selected = false

        // on va creer le tableau de SKAction
        blocArray[blocSelectedArray[index]].animateBloc()
    }

    // vider le tableau des blocs selectionne
    blocSelectedArray.removeAll()

    // on reinitialise le nombre calculé
    numberComputed = 0
}
```

what i mean append is the unselect start after the last SKAction running is not finished
My question is what i must to do to wait all actions of all GameBloc are finished before running other new SKAction.

Regards,
Sorry for the first incomplete post.

Comment: You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50491768/edit) your question to include the actual code you use that generates the problem in the form of a [mcve].

Comment: Hi i have edited my question with sample of my code.